# string operation in rails module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, symbols

```
class Music < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :counter, :video, :video_file_name

   def name

    last=video_file_name.rindex('.') //line 1
    video_file_name[last,4]="" //line 2
    video_file_name //line3
  end
end
```

I have one Music class, and want to define a `name` method, that I can use it in the view like: `@music.name`. Now, I can get the value of `video_file_name.rindex('.')` in line 1, but I can not use it (last) in line 2. It says `"no implicit conversion from nil to integer"`. if i change the last variable to a number, it will work.

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that `last` is `nil`

`rindex` returns `nil` if it cannot find the substring you are looking for.

Thus

```
last = video_file_name.rindex('.')
# last is nil because it does not contain a .
video_file_name[last, 4]="" # this line will crash because you are giving a nil index
```

Comment: Hi alexBrand, thanks, i agree with you but the point is if i run video_file_name.rindex('.'), i can get value 11. When i assign it to last, last still is nil. Do you have idea for that?

Comment: How are you running that line? In the console? If you run it and you are getting 11, then I don't see how assigning it to a variable would make it nil.

Comment: hi alex, i run it in modles. It seems that i can not put variable in [,].